# Using more than one subscription in a method

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription

In my Angular app, I want to display a detailed summary of my sales for a given drink. For this, I'm using the `DrinkDetailComponent`. When initialising the component, I need to do 2 backend calls to retrieve all information I need: `getSalesHistory()` and `getDrink()`, however, my method only executes the `getSalesHistory()` method, and not the `getDrink()` one.

I've logged something small just to see if the subscriptions ran, which only one of them does. What am I doing wrong here?

`DrinkDetailComponent`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { SalesHistoryService } from 'src/app/sales-history/sales-history.service';
import { Drink } from '../drink';
import { DrinksService } from '../drinks.service';
import { DrinkOverview } from './dto/drinkoverview.dto';
import { SalesHistory } from './dto/saleshistory.dto';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './drinkdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drinkdetail.component.css']
})
export class DrinkDetailComponent {
  private routeSub!: Subscription;
  drinkOverview: DrinkOverview;
  salesHistory: SalesHistory;
  private drink!: Drink;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private drinksService: DrinksService, private salesHistoryService: SalesHistoryService) {
    this.salesHistory = {
      name: '',
      sales: []
    };

    this.drinkOverview = {
      name: '',
      startPrice: 0,
      currentPrice: 0,
      averagePrice: 0,
      numberSold: 0,
      totalIncome: 0
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getDrinkDetails(params['name']);      
    });
  }

  getDrinkDetails(name: string) {
    this.drinksService.getDrink(name).subscribe(drinkLocal => {
      this.drink = drinkLocal;
      this.drinkOverview.name = this.salesHistory.name;
      console.log('sub2')
    });

    this.salesHistoryService.getSalesHistory(name).subscribe(salesHistoryLocal => {
      this.salesHistory = {
        name: salesHistoryLocal.name,
        sales: salesHistoryLocal.sales
      };
      console.log('sub') // Only this subscription runs

    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

`DrinksService`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LocalService } from '../local/local.service';
import { CreateDrinkDto } from './create/createdrink.dto';
import { Drink } from './drink';
import { SellDrinkDto } from './selldrink.dto';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DrinksService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private localService: LocalService) { }

  private url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/drinks';
  drinks: Drink[] = [];

  getDrinks(): Observable<Drink[]> {
    console.log('Getting drinks from backend')
    return this.http.get<Drink[]>(this.url);
  }

  getDrink(name: string): Observable<Drink> {
    console.log('Getting drink: ' + name)
    return this.http.get<Drink>(this.url + '/' + name)
  }

  ...
}
```

`SalesHistoryService`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SalesHistory } from './dto/saleshistory.dto';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SalesHistoryService {

  private url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/sales-history/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSalesHistory(name: string): Observable<SalesHistory> {
    return this.http.get<SalesHistory>(this.url + name);
  }


}
```

Comment: The approach seems fine. Does the same subscription always fail? Did you make sure your api works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a matter of the backend not working, and not this approach.

The backend did return the correct objects when I called them from Postman, but did not do anything when called from the Angular app. I've resolved that now, so this code is actually fine.

FYI, the NestJS backend original code:

```
@Controller('drinks')
export class DrinksController {
    constructor(private drinksService: DrinksService, private salesHistoryService: SalesHistoryService) {}
    private readonly logger = new Logger(DrinksController.name);

    @Get(':name')
    async getDrinkByName(@Param() params: any, @Res() res: Response): Promise<DrinkDto> {
        this.logger.log("GET: details for " + params.name);
        let drink = this.drinksService.getDrinkByName(params.name);
        if(drink !== null) {
            return drink;
        } else {
            res.status(404);
        }
    }

    ...              
}
```

The new backend code

```
@Controller('drinks')
export class DrinksController {
    constructor(private drinksService: DrinksService, private salesHistoryService: SalesHistoryService) {}
    private readonly logger = new Logger(DrinksController.name);

    @Get(':name')
    async getDrinkByName(@Param() params: any, @Res() res: Response) {
        this.logger.log("GET: details for " + params.name);
        let drink = this.drinksService.getDrinkByName(params.name);
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
        if(drink !== null) {
            res.send(drink);
        } else {
            res.status(404);
            res.send();
        }
    }

    ...              
}
```